# Apache Reverse Proxy Keeps me in the login Page

Tags: apache, cookies, proxy, reverse

I have a problem with the apache reverse proxy configuration..
I have a service running on port 3000 and when i try to do the login even if it's succesfull it keeps me in the login page..i think it's a cookie session problem but i can't figure out a solution..

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<proxy *>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</proxy>
ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "http://127.0.0.1:3000/" "http:foo/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration finally works..

```
<VirtualHost *:*>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName http://localhost
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyErrorOverride On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user    
RequestHeader unset Authorization
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```